# Separate my integers

Tags: code-golf, math, array, topology

### Introduction

In the field of mathematics known as [topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology), there are things called [separation axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom).
Intuitively, you have a set `X` and a collection of subsets of `X`, which we can think of as properties.
The system is well separated, if one can distinguish between all items of `X` based on their properties.
The separation axioms formalize this idea.
In this challenge, your task is to check three separation axioms, given `X` and the list of properties.

### Input

Your inputs are an integer `n ≥ 2`, and a list of lists `T` of integers.
The integers in `T` are drawn from `X = [0, 1, ..., n-1]`.
The lists in `T` may be empty and unsorted, but they will not contain duplicates.

### Output

Your output is one of four strings, determined by three separation axioms, each stronger than the last.
There are other axioms, but we stick with these for simplicity.

- Suppose that for all distinct `x` and `y` in `X`, there exists a list in `T` containing exactly one of them.
  Then `X` and `T` satisfy *axiom T0*.
- Suppose that for all distinct `x` and `y` in `X`, there exist two lists in `T`, one of which contains `x` but not `y`, and the other contains `y` but not `x`.
  Then `X` and `T` satisfy *axiom T1*.
- Suppose that the two lists above also contain no common elements.
  Then `X` and `T` satisfy *axiom T2*.

Your output is one of `T2`, `T1`, `T0` or `TS`, depending on which of the above conditions holds (`TS` means none of them do).
Note that T2 is stronger than T1, which is stronger than T0, and you should always output the strongest possible axiom.

### Rules and scoring

You can write a full program or a function.
The lowest byte count wins, and standard loopholes are disallowed.

### Test cases

```
2 [] -> TS
2 [[],[1]] -> T0
2 [[0],[1]] -> T2
3 [[0],[0,1,2],[1,2]] -> TS
3 [[],[0],[0,1],[2]] -> T0
3 [[0],[0,1],[2,1],[0,1,2]] -> T0
3 [[0],[0,1],[2,1],[2,0]] -> T1
6 [[0,2,4],[0,3,5],[1,2],[3,4,5]] -> TS
6 [[0,2,4],[0,3,5],[1,2],[2,5],[3,4,5]] -> T0
6 [[0,2,4],[0,3,5],[1,2],[2,5],[3,1],[3,4,5]] -> T1
6 [[0,1],[0,2,3],[1,4],[2,4],[2,3,5],[1,3],[4,5]] -> T2
```

Comment: Is the input `n` superfluous? In the rest of the challenge, I'm not seeing it used beyond defining what elements can be in `T`, so is it just a provided shortcut for `T.Maximum()`?

Comment: @TimmyD, no. See the first test case. `0 []` should give `T2`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Aaaahhhhhhhh. Thanks, that helps tremendously.

Comment: Great explanation of what separability means!

Comment: @LuisMendo Weird terminology alert: These are separation axioms, and a topological spaces that satisfies T2 is sometimes called separated, but [separability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_space) is something else entirely.

Comment: @Dennis Hm you're right, I mixed those up

Answer (score 9):

## Haskell, <s>317</s> <s>209</s> <s>174</s> 168 bytes

The function f does the job.

```haskell
(#)=elem
x?y=[1|a<-x,b<-y,not$any(#a)b]
f n l|t(++)="TS"|t zip="T0"|t(?)="T1"|1>0="T2"where
    t p=any null[p(x%y)(y%x)|x<-[0..n-1],y<-[0..x-1]]
    x%y=[z|z<-l,x#z,not$y#z]
```

tests :

```haskell
main=do
    putStrLn $ f 2 []
    putStrLn $ f 2 [[],[1]]
    putStrLn $ f 2 [[0],[1]]
    putStrLn $ f 3 [[0],[0,1,2],[1,2]]
    putStrLn $ f 3 [[],[0],[0,1],[2]]
    putStrLn $ f 3 [[0],[0,1],[2,1],[0,1,2]]
    putStrLn $ f 3 [[0],[0,1],[2,1],[2,0]]
    putStrLn $ f 6 [[0,2,4],[0,3,5],[1,2],[3,4,5]]
    putStrLn $ f 6 [[0,2,4],[0,3,5],[1,2],[2,5],[3,4,5]]
    putStrLn $ f 6 [[0,2,4],[0,3,5],[1,2],[2,5],[3,1],[3,4,5]]
    putStrLn $ f 6 [[0,1],[0,2,3],[1,4],[2,4],[2,3,5],[1,3],[4,5]]
```

output:

```haskell
TS
T0
T2
TS
T0
T0
T1
TS
T0
T1
T2
```

Comment: Giving `t` a function as input is a clever trick!

Comment: In absence of competition, this bounty goes to your answer. Congratulations!

Comment: some free bytes - replace `f` by an operator name, and replace `p(x%y)(x%y)` by `p(x%y)$x%y`. and by the way, nice work!